# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_by' and 'updated_by' cannot be null

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to solve this issue from yesterday. There is an issue in my update method and I can't figure it out.
I have been trying to update my foreign key of the `services` table.

User created a service and now I want to change the name of the user that created it and that updated it but nothing is happening I am getting this issue again and again.

This is my form field of the edit.blade.php
[image: edit.blade.php]

And this is the update method of my Controller:
[image: controller-update-method]

I have tried many things, searched for thousand of things , watched for almost 10 times still nothing happened.

Comment: It's pretty clear that either the `created_by` or `updated_by` field is not being filled in,  You aren't checking for that in your code.

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of images.

Comment: Service::findOrFail($service_id)->update([

            'created_by' => $request->created_by,
            'updated_by' => $request->updated_by,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'slug' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-',$request->title)),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'image' =>  $save_url,
        ]);

        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Service Updated With Image Successfully',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
     thats my update method

Comment: add dd($request->all()); in controller method and check you receiving created_by and Updated_by value or not.

Comment: its showls null

Comment: even thoguh i am putting values of created_at and updated_at

Comment: Please **edit your answer** and replace the images with actual code. Posting it as a comment won't do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some things to do:

1. inspect the values of your options to check if they are actually set and not `value=""`
2. inspect the values of your request server side by `dd($request->all())`
3. make sure your fields exist in your model's `$fillable` array

Comment: I did that it is showing null

Comment: I gave 3 points, what is "that"? did you check all 3? what part is showing null?

Comment: yeah i models i assigned protected $guarded and value are already checked when i open edit page
and dd($request->all) is showing null even after i changes the value of created_by and updated_by

Comment: Thanks bro You saved my day The issue was because of not assigning $fillable property instead i was using $guarded property now it is resolved thank God!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `created_by` and `updated_by` values from request is valid or not

```
dd($request->created_by)
dd($request->updated_by)
```